# Type Conversion in C++ from Short Array to Const short* const*

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, webrtc, type-conversion

i have an Array of **Short Data Type**, My Need is to Convert **short Array[]** into **const short* const*** . As i am Working on Webrtc Noise Suppression Module, and as i pull webrtc Library, then it gives me Type Conversion Problem.

**Solution i Tried:**

1. reinterpret_cast (Run Time Error)
2. const_cast(Compile Time Error)

**Snippet of Code, where i am Facing Problem :**

```
short tempBuffer[320] = {"Some Data" ...};
short recvBuffer[320] = {'\0'};

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{

 WebRtcNsx_Process(NSRx, (&tempBuffer[test_]), 1, 
 (&recvBuffer[test_]));
 test_ += 80;

}
```

**Question:**

**WebRtcNsx_Process Functions 2nd Argument should be **const short* const***, so How To Convert a **short Array** to **const short* const***

Comment: Omit the dereferencing index, this function wants the address of the array apparently.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ , Thanks That Solved My Compilation Issue as well as RunRime Crash, But My Noise Quality Degrades a Lot.. so this Way of Giving Input Seems Wrong..

Comment: oh Great man, it was Another Issue.. it Works Like a Charm..!!!! :-) Thanks..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If you are suggesting `&tempBuffer`, that is wrong. `&tempBuffer` is a *pointer to an array*, of type `short (*)[320]`, whereas the function wants a *pointer to a pointer*, of type `short **`.

Comment: @user102008 Oh boy! How did you land here that late? I think I merely meant `&recvBuffer`, but probably that question should be closed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The same thing is true for `&recvBuffer`. It's not the right type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just Need to Typedef Short Array in ios XCode 6.4, wherever Concern with Webrtc Noise Suppression Function **WebRtcNsx_Process** , the Second Argument Need to be Passed as an Address of Buffer Array only. i Got My Answer from πάντα ῥεῖ, Thanks Again.